# should we use spring webflow on a fresh project even if its decreased development activity

Tags: spring-webflow

In our organization, we'd like to use JSF 2.0, Primefaces and Spring Webflow on a fresh big web app project. In examples we see that those stack integrates well enough.

But we are concerned about the development activity and support for Spring Webflow. In the project [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF) there are releases that are long overdue. Is SWF going to be discarded from Spring Portfolio and not supported any more? Should we use it in our fresh projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/06/martin-lippert-sstoolsuite-2-6), in STS 2.6 there is a graphical Web Flow editor, so it's not totally abandoned, though in [fisheye](https://fisheye.springsource.org/graph/spring-webflow) there is basically no activity, download page isn't refreshed to newest version etc.

Unless you have have some serious reason (like having developers with massive JSF knowledge), I'd recommend against Web Flow and would go for GWT or Wicket. (Though if I'd go the JSF way, I'd choose exactly the stack you described)

Answer (score 2):

There are major alternatives for the backend of JSF other than Spring WebFlow like Seam3 and Java EE's CDI.